# Modifying a squashfs

Tags: squashfs

I am having a problem recompiling this `squashfile` with the same file format. Here's the file I already tried with `squashfs` 3.4 but the problem is I am missing something with non-standard signature.

```
http://qw12.cf/aa/initrd.zip
```

Please help me. I have no idea how I can make it.

[image]

Comment: what's the problem exactly?

Comment: i can extract it but cant recompile it with the same file format

Comment: rex@debian:~/Downloads$ binwalk bx3      <<<    HERE IS THE FILE I MADE

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 3.1

rex@debian:~/Downloads$ binwalk initrd.img, <<< ORIGINAL FILE

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature,  version 3.1

Comment: use `squashfs-tools` version 3.x. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57455/squashfs-3-vs-4

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).  To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yeah sir. i have done it already but my problem is my compiled squashfs is not a non-standard-signature

Comment: i take a screenshot here is the difference http://tinypic.com/r/wrg84m/9 @IporSircer

Comment: please help me also @gertvdijk